# Error reading csv file in pandas with quotation

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file using pandas with the following line:

```
df = pd.read_csv('BLOCKS-0-100000.csv', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')
```

The problem is I have this value in one of the records:

```
"[\"0x27d49d2c20203f4e6332d75898dc96f10db405951df6b5bcd8b8246087b4b382,0x26870f44764828d6bad7ce106c98bc5231dfd3e0d88607b9cd31927a6c0bf811\"]"
```

I have nested quotation and pandas is given me the following error:

`pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 13 fields in line 577, saw 14`

I've also tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('BLOCKS-0-100000.csv', header=0, sep=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Any idea on how to debug this, without modifying the file?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If the file isn't too large, you could load it in memory as a whole, repair the data and feed it into `read_csv`.

Comment: Or edit the file manually if this is a one time thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `escapechar` key-word argument of the `read_csv` function:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('BLOCKS-0-100000.csv', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')
```

This will escape the `quotechar`s that are preceeded by a `\`, and therefore will work for your input, since you have twice `\"`.